# How to set an empty space as constant in Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I tried to set a String with an empty space as a constant in Camel.

```
from("timer:test?fixedRate=true&period=5000")
    .setBody().constant(" ")
    .log("'${body}'")
;
```

It seems not to work, because the above code prints '' as log output.

I'm using Camel Version 2.23.1 and figured out that the method *constant* in the Class *ExpressionClauseSupport* needs to set the Attribute trim to *true* when creating the *ConstantExpression*. See [the creation of the Object](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.23.1/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/builder/ExpressionClauseSupport.java#L89) and [the trimming](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.23.1/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/model/language/ExpressionDefinition.java#L202-L206) of the constant String.

In my opinion a constant should not be trimmed or am I wrong?

Comment: What about using a StringBuilder instead of a plain String?  It could be a workaround.

Comment: Good idea for a workaround @pino!
But, of course, it is not a long term solution for the problem, because StringBuilder is a mutable Object and the defined instance could be changed when the route is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this ?

```
ConstantExpression exp = new ConstantExpression(" ");
exp.setTrim(false);

from("timer:test?fixedRate=true&period=5000")
.setBody(exp)
.log("'${body}'");
```

Comment: Thanks. This really helped!